# Why does my tunneled IPv6 connectivity drop after a short period of time?

Tags: centos, ipv6, tunneling

I correctly setup a Hurricane Electric tunnel on a CentOS 6.5 VPS server (KVM). I use CSF (ConfigServer Security & Firewall) which acts as a wrapper for iptables and ip6tables, the default services themselves are disabled.

Tunnel interface: sit1
WAN interface: eth0

I have a IPv6 address set on the WAN, along with several IPV6ADDR_SECONDARIES.

Initially connectivity is great. I can use ping6/traceroute6 to ping and trace IPv6 sites. However after a short period of time IPv6 connectivity goes down, all IPv6 requests timeout and no communication can be made via IPv6 any longer.

If I flush the firewall i.e. disable it, everyting works again, if I restart the firewall, IPv6 connectivity works for a short while before going down again. It seems unless I flush the firewall connectivity is completely blocked until doing so.

What could be the reason for this? Do I need to add specific firewall entries in addition to the configuration provided by CSF, or am I experiencing problems because IPv6 connectivity is coming over a tunnel interface and then being accessed via the WAN (eth0)?

Thanks for any help the community can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears I overlooked my iptables firewall, the problem doesn't appear to be with ip6tables but actually proto 41 being blocked which is required for 6in4 to work, I added the following to my csfpre.sh file:

```
iptables -t filter -I INPUT -p 41 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -I OUTPUT -p 41 -j ACCEPT
```

Connectivity appears to be maintained now.